# Find a string inside a string / another way to set values from cin?

Tags: c++, find

the task I have at hand is:

When user inputs a string

```
config.min=//some number
config.max=//some number
config.some_other_parameter=//some number
```

I need to identify the type of parameter in question (min, max, etc...), and extract the number behind the `=` sign.

Finding a string using `str.find` crossed my mind (for example `position = str.find("config.min=")`, and find the character behind it), but then the number can be 2 or more digits, and I am done.

I came from a semester of C, so I am not familiar with all the functions of c++. Is there a way around this? Or do i really need to browse the string like that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), but I would suggest looking for just the `=` character by itself.  Then use [`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to extract the name and value portions, eg:

```cpp
std::string str = ...;

std::string::size_type position = str.find('=');
std::string name = str.substr(0, position);
std::string value = str.substr(position+1);

if (name == "config.min") {
    ...
}
if (name == "config.max") {
    ...
}
if (name == "config.some_other_parameter") {
    ...
}
...
```

Then you can use `name` and `value` as needed.

Comment: Thanks, will try. Why size_t and not int?

Comment: Because that is what `find()` actually returns, and what `substr()` actually takes. Don't mix types unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code: (It will save numbers in num[i].)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 string str;
 //if user input space between string, you have to use getline
 getline(cin,str);
 int pos=0;
 string str_temp;
 int num[3];

 for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    pos = str.find("=",pos+1);
    str_temp = str.substr(pos+1);
    num[i] = stoi(str_temp);
 }

cout<<num[0]<<endl<<num[1]<<endl<<num[2];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is starting to make sense for me now!